# Why is my AJAX call in jQuery not working?

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

What am I trying to achieve:

- After form is being filled-out and submit button being clicked, I want to be able to submit form and do an AJAX call - `payment.php` file (I did integration of PayPal, I am sending following values via mail `firstname`, `surname`, `email`, `phone`, `number`, `date of birth`, `CV`, `photo`, etc...) and I am also trying to store it into the database.

Where am I failing at?

This is multiple-step form, the problem is occuring when I get to the last step of filling-out form and by clicking "Submit" button nothing happens - my AJAX call is not working...

---

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var opacity;
var current = 1;
var steps = $("fieldset").length;

setProgressBar(current);

$(".next").click(function(){
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    
    //Add Class Active
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    
    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now) {
            // for making fielset appear animation
            opacity = 1 - now;

            current_fs.css({
                'display': 'none',
                'position': 'relative'
            });
            next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 500
    });
    setProgressBar(++current);
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    
    //Remove class active
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    
    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();

    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now) {
            // for making fielset appear animation
            opacity = 1 - now;

            current_fs.css({
                'display': 'none',
                'position': 'relative'
            });
            previous_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 500
    });
    setProgressBar(--current);
});

function setProgressBar(curStep){
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar")
      .css("width",percent+"%")   
}

$(".submit").click(function(){
    var request;
        //moj kod 
        event.preventDefault();
    
    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $("#msform");
    
    
    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    
    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    
    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    
    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "payment.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });
    
    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Request uspješno poslat!");
    });
    
    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
        console.error(
            "Desio se sljedeci error: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
        
    });
    
    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
    
        //moj kod ->end
    return false;
    })
    
    });
```

This is jQuery code (obviously) - and here I am handling the form and its data (at least it's what I intended to do with it)

This is form inside of HTML:

```
 <form class="paypal" action="payment.php" method="post" name="Form" id="msform">
                    <?php 
                            $paket = $_GET['paket'];
                            if($paket == "standard")
                            {
                                ?> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="standard" value="standard">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                                <?php
                            }
                            else if($paket == "bewerbungscheck")
                            {
                                ?> <input type="hidden" name="bewerbungscheck" value="bewerbungscheck">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2">
                                <?php
                            }
                            else if($paket == "premium")
                            {
                                ?> <input type="hidden" name="premium" value="premium">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="3">
                                <?php
                            }
                            else if($paket == "lowbudget")
                            {
                                ?> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="lowbudget" value="lowbudget">
                                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="4">
                                <?php
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "There's no package with this name, please go back and choose again, wisely!";
                                ?>
                                <button class="btn">
                                <a href="https://meinegutebewerbung.de/">Go Back</a>
                                </button>
                                <?php
                                exit();
                            }
                            ?>
                        <!-- progressbar -->
                        <ul id="progressbar">
                            <li class="active" id="account"><strong>Personal Info</strong></li>
                            <li id="personal"><strong>Appointment</strong></li>
                            <li id="payment"><strong>Documents</strong></li>
                            <li id="confirm"><strong>Finish</strong></li>
                            
                        </ul>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar"
                                aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <!-- fieldsets -->
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-card">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Information:</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-5">
                                        <h2 class="steps">Step 1 - 4</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- FOR PAYPAL -->
                                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="Customer's First Name" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="Customer's Last Name" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="payer_email" name="payer_email" value="customer@example.com" />
                                <!-- END OF SECTION FOR PAYPAL -->
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Email: *</label>
                                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@meinegutebewerbung.de" />
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Name: *</label>
                                <input id="fn" type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Name" />
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Surname: *</label>
                                <input id="sur" type="text" name="usur" placeholder="Surname" />
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Expertised in: *</label>
                                <input type="text" name="expert" placeholder="ex.:Bachelor in Computer science" />
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Phone number: *</label>
                                <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="+000000000000000" />
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Birth Date: *</label>
                                <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" />
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" name="next" onclick="populate()" class="next action-button"
                                value="Next" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-card">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <h2 class="fs-title">Appointment details:</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-5">
                                        <h2 class="steps">Step 2 - 4</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Select appointment date: *</label>
                                <input id="date_picker" type="date" name="date-res" />
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Which time span is the most fitting for you: *</label> <br>
                                <select name="suitabletime " id="suitable">
                                    <option value="09-14">09:00 - 14:00</option>
                                    <option value="14-20">14:00 - 20:00</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous"
                                value="Previous" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-card">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <h2 class="fs-title">Upload documents:</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-5">
                                        <h2 class="steps">Step 3 - 4</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Upload Your Photo:</label>
                                <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
                                <label class="fieldlabels">Upload CV (must be PDF):</label>
                                <input type="file" name="pic" accept=".pdf">
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Submit" />
                            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous"
                                value="Previous" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-card">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <h2 class="fs-title">Finish:</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-5">
                                        <h2 class="steps">Step 4 - 4</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br><br>
                                <h2 class="purple-text text-center"><strong>SUCCESS !</strong></h2>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="col-3">
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GwStPmg.png" class="fit-image">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br><br>
                                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="col-7 text-center">
                                        <h5 class="purple-text text-center">You Have Successfully Signed Up</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

How did I came to conclusion that this is not working?

- I have actually inserted console.log() so I can get some output after the code is executed, but I am not getting anything. The second thing is that I also setted up PHP to do echo and again I am not getting anything.

Comment: I don't see `$('.submit')` in your html

Comment: It is there `$(".submit").click(function(){ //code...`

Comment: There's no button with class "submit" **in your html**

Comment: Well, now it actually works... I will have to get pair of glasses for myself... Thank you @kikon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kikon already stated inside of the comments, the problem was that I did not put the `class="submit"` as a attribute to the `<button>`, therefore element with the class of `submit` didn't exist, so the jQuery couldn't trigger the code inside of the function for AJAX.